# Create a dataframe To detail information of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe with the value and number of payments and the start date. id like to create a new dataframe with the all the payments one row per month.
Can you guys give a tip about how to finish it?

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [[1,'2017-06-09',300,3]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','DATE','VALUE','PAYMENTS']) 

# print dataframe. 
df
```

EXISTING DATAFRAME FIELDS:

[image]

DATAFRAME DESIRED, open the payments and update the date:
[image]

My first thought was to make a loop appending the payments. But if in this loop i already put the other fields and generate de new data frame, so the task would be done.

```
result = [] 
for value in df["PAYMENTS"]: 
if value == 1: 
    result.append(1) 
elif value ==3: 
    for x in range(1,4):
        result.append(x) 
else: 
    for x in range(1,7):
        result.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

```
df.VALUE = df.VALUE / df.PAYMENTS
df = df.merge(df.ID.repeat(df.PAYMENTS), on='ID', how='outer')
df.PAYMENTS = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
   ID        DATE  VALUE  PAYMENTS
0   1  2017-06-09  100.0         1
1   1  2017-06-09  100.0         2
2   1  2017-06-09  100.0         3
```

Comment: hello tks my friend ill try it out!

Comment: well, it doesnt worked for me when i tryed in the real df